# Mathematica -- turning a list into a partition of element positions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I would like to make a function that takes in a list of integers and returns a partition of the indices of the list, based on the elements of the list.

For instance:

```
{1,3,3,7} --> { {1}, {2,3}, {4}}
{3,1,3} --> {{1,3}, {2}}
```

I can think of messy ways to do this, but is there a natural way to do this in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
indicies[x_] := Reap[MapIndexed[Sow[#2, #] &, x]][[2, All, All, 1]]
```

This will be *much* faster than repeatedly using `Position`, on a long lists with many unique elements.  Example:

```
list = RandomInteger[9999, 10000];

Timing[
  result1 =
    Function[x, (Flatten@Position[x, #] &) /@ DeleteDuplicates[x]]@list;
]
```

> ```
> {3.463, Null}
> ```

```
Timing[
  result2 = indicies @ list;
]
```

> ```
> {0.031, Null}
> ```

```
result1 === result2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

---

`TomD` suggested using the newer `GatherBy` in place of `Sow` and `Reap`.  This is even faster on long lists with little repetition.

```
indicies2[x_] := GatherBy[List ~MapIndexed~ x, First][[All, All, 2, 1]]

list2 = RandomInteger[99999, 100000];

Do[indicies @ list2, {10}] // Timing
Do[indicies2 @ list2, {10}] // Timing
```

> ```
> {5.523, Null}
>
> {2.823, Null}
> ```

Speed is more similar on lists with greater repetition:

```
list3 = RandomInteger[99, 100000];

Do[indicies @ list3, {10}] // Timing
Do[indicies2 @ list3, {10}] // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.716, Null}
>
> {1.607, Null}
> ```

If going for pure speed one must recognize that `MapIndexed` is not optimized for packed arrays, therefore `Range` and `Transpose` will be considerably faster in that case:

```
indicies3[x_] := GatherBy[{x, Range@Length@x}\[Transpose], First][[All, All, 2]]

Do[indicies3 @ list2, {10}] // Timing
```

> ```
> {1.981, Null}
> ```

```
Do[indicies3@list3, {10}] // Timing  (* big difference here *)
```

> ```
> {0.125, Null}
> ```

Comment: The execution speed of the two methods seems to be dependent on the content of the list. For a list of 1,000,000 length,containing only two values, `indicies` ( `indices` ?)  was a fraction slower at 0.78s versus 0.71s.

Comment: Much more elegant. `GatherBy[MapIndexed[{#1,#2}&,list],First][[All, All,2,1]]` as a variant?

Comment: @image_doctor well yes, if `Position` is only called a couple of times it will be fast, and I didn't mean to imply otherwise.  I guess I should have said "for many unique elements" rather than for long lists.

Comment: @TomD More elegant?  I'm not sure I can agree; I really have a fondness for `Sow` and `Reap`. :-)   Faster though, probably, and I really should learn to use the shiny new `GatherBy` more often. (And it isn't very new anymore!)  If we're going for elegance you should get rid of that `&` function: `GatherBy[List ~MapIndexed~ x, First][[All, All, 2, 1]]`

Comment: @TomD Yes, I missed the stop. <:-o  Thanks. :-)

Comment: To clarify, I meant: 'Much more elegant _than my method_. A variant is ...' (+1 to Mr. Wizard).

Answer (score 1):

One possibility:

```
Function[x, (Flatten@Position[x, #] &) /@ DeleteDuplicates[x]]@{1, 3, 
  3, 7}
```

giving

```
(*  {{1}, {2, 3}, {4}  *)
```

Another example:

```
lst = {1, 3, 3, 3, 7, 4, 3};
Function[x, (Flatten@Position[x, #] &) /@ DeleteDuplicates[x]]@lst
```

giving:

```
(*{{1}, {2, 3, 4, 7}, {5}, {6}}*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach:

```
f[x_] := Flatten[x~Position~First@#] & /@ Gather@x
```